# Change keyboard shortcut for sidebar in sublime text 2

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext2

Currently the shortcut to hide or show the sidebar is cmd K, cmd B.

I would like it just be cmd K.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sure, you can edit it like any other keyboard shortcut from Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Key Bindings - User:

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+k"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" }
]
```

Note that this will disable all the other shortcuts with a ⌘K prefix, such as the ones for converting case and folding, even though they'll still show up in the menus.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Preferences > Key Bindings - Default`, find `toggle_side_bar`, remove `cmd+b` and save.

Comment: Nicholas' answer is better, I wanted to keep it as simple as I could.

Comment: Actually you should do under User not Default as Default is overwritten on app upgrades while User prefs are saved.

Answer (score 0):

and in Windows:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text won't let you edit any of the text for the hotkeys.